How to interpolate height of point on TIN in PostGIS
I want to be able to interpolate the height of a point on a TIN surface in PostGIS.
For example the code below is (I believe) creating a minimal TIN with just one triangle.  I want the height of this surface at location (1250,1100), which I believe should be 150.0.
Below I tried using ST_intersection of a 2D point with the TIN.  This does output a point with the correct X and Y coordinates, and generate a Z coordinate.  But the Z value is not the height of the TIN at that X,Y value. I have tried other coordinates and ST_intersection seems to return either the height of one of the TIN nodes, or the height of the centroid of the triangle.
Does anyone know a correct way to do this in PostGIS?
SELECT st_astext(
    st_intersection(
        'POINT(1250 1100)'::geometry,
    'TIN Z (((1000.0 1000.0 100.0, 2000.0 1800.0 500.0, 2000 1000.0 100.0, 1000.0 1000.0 100.0)))'::geometry
));


Output:
        st_astext        
-------------------------
 POINT Z (1250 1100 100)



As a hint: get the ST_3DIntersection bewteen the TIN and a (pseudo-infinite; i.e. long enough) vertical LineString through your point.
